# Recessed lighting in existing concrete light fixture

Tags: lighting, concrete, ceiling, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I have some light fixtures that are currently used and covered with blind plates in the corners of a concrete ceiling room. I was wonder if there was anyway to convert those existing light boxes to recessed lighting. The wiring is already done but i imagine id need to get a deep hole.

Comment: Do you mean they are currently "unused"? My other question is whether you have existing recessed lights or just unused junction boxes with covers on them? The difference is you can't put a "can" light inside a standard junction box.

Comment: yea its just an unused junction box since the ceiling is solid concrete they added a few extra spots.

Answer (score 1):

If the boxes in the concrete are round boxes, there are LEDs that give the look of recessed lights. Here is a [link](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-in-Soft-White-Recessed-LED-Can-Disk-Light-E-CE-JB4-600L-27K-E26/203596702) to a source for them. They can only go in a box with a few wires in them, they fill it up pretty well.

Comment: those do look cool but it 3O bucks for the bulb? what if it burns out? Do i need to replace the whole unit?

Comment: It is not just the bulb, but the trim, transformer everything. There are supposed to last 10 years. It is a very cheap alternative to a VERY expensive idea you first posed.

Comment: I mean it is a nice idea but ive heard they dont last as long as it would seem cuase they calculate 1O but if you only use it 3 hours a day.

Comment: @Learner, this is BY FAR your best option considering the situation. IMO $30 is a bargain for such a solution. I've used similar lights and they work great.

Comment: well after looking at them it looks about as good as its going to get. I just want to turn my house into a classier affair. After all this house is in Ecuador and recessed lighting all kinds of high styling down there

Answer (score 0):

From you comment that these are indeed junction boxes in a concrete ceiling, I would answer your question by saying...

No, it is not worth it to change them to recessed lighting.

There are many very attractive fixtures manufactured to attach to a standard octagon junction box on the ceiling. Some will mount very low profile if you are worried about head clearance. Most come with mounting plated that can adapt to a device box also. If these are 4" square boxes you will need to modify a blank plate or buy an adapter plate for a light fixture.

Good luck!